# Using array elements to assign “id=” values returns: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write calculated values to table cells referencing them by their `id=` tag that are chosen using array elements. All attempts to get this working such as where `“ “` are coded, and first trying `spans[index]= spans[index].toString();` and using `window.setTimeout(function () { code.. }, 0);` gives the above error.

The many of the similar questions that I have found posted have responses suggesting that the error is related to page loading.

I am either misunderstanding the solutions given or what I'm attempting is different. It would be  appreciated if someone could give an example of how this is accomplished.

```
function outputResults() {
    var spans = ['span1', 'span2', 'span3'];
    var outputs = ['output1', 'output2', 'output3'];

    for (var index = 0; index < spans.length; index++)
    { 
        outputs[index] = (outputs[index] * 13) / 100;
        (document.getElementById('\'spans[index]\'').innerHtml = outputs[index]);
    };
};
```

```
<table BORDER="1" width="300" />
    <tr />
        <td /> <span id="span1">&nbsp;</span> </td>
        <td /> <span id="span2">&nbsp;</span> </td>
        <td /> <span id="span3">&nbsp;</span> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click to fill cells" onclick="outputResults();" />
```

Comment: Why are you trying to multiply a string like `'output1'` with 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's look at this line:

```
outputs[index] = (outputs[index] * 13) / 100;
```

What do you expect to happend here? Say index equals 0. outputs[0] == 'output1'. Your assignment is doing this (meta):

```
outputs[0] = ('output1' * 13) / 100;
```

You should revise this statement. As to your error, this should work for you:

```
document.getElementById(spans[index]).innerHtml = outputs[index];
```

EDIT:
There are a lot of problems with your code. You need to fix your HTML (self-closed td and tr tags) and your JavaScript code (outputs values and innerHTML). Please see working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pkRmC/2/

Comment: Thanks @Bergi and King. I should follow the rule "turn brain on". the blah * 13 /100 I'd stuck in to initialize things and clearly wasn't thinking at all well. As for the extra /'s I'd copied other code without paying attention and would have got to them after getting the output function working (another rule: Best to code it yourself). You may guess I've just started using HTML & javascript and have a way to go yet. Just hadn't considered omitting the quotes - but if nothing else it'll be the one thing I learn today.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.getElementById(spans[index])` if you don't want to select the (nonexisting) element with the literal id "`'spans[index]'`".

Btw, all your opening tags do incorrectly end with `/>`, while it should be just `>`. Not sure how you did not get a big HTML parse error from that. The `/>` syntax is only permitted for self-closing elements such as `hr`, `br`, `meta` etc, and actually is only necessary in XHTML.

Also, your computation of `outputs[index] * 13) / 100` does not make too much sense, since you are multiplying a string with the number `13` - which will result in `NaN`. Not sure what you wanted to achieve with that.